# Ansible: undefined variable when copying file on local

Tags: ansible, yaml, devops

im about to make an ansible playbook for automatic updating some librarys

> **The error msg i got :**
>   "msg": "The task includes an option with an undefined variable. The
>   error was: 'lib_wheel_path' is undefined\n\nThe error appears to
>   be in '/home/user/Desktop/setup/roles/lib/tasks/main.yml': line 4,
>   column 3, but may\nbe elsewhere in the file depending on the exact
>   syntax problem.\n\nThe offending line appears to be:\n\n\n- name:
>   Download lib\n  ^ here\n"

my **ansible/vars** file contains the path to libs :

```
local_path: "~/Some_Libraries/"
lib_wheel_path: "{{ local_path }}lib/"
```

the **ansible/role/lib/vars/main.yml** file contains :

```
lib_path: "{{ lib_wheel_path }}"
lib_wheels: "'{{ lib_path }}' | regex_findall('(lib\\S*\\.whl)') | sort(reverse=True) }}"
```

the **ansible/role/lib/tasks/main.yml** file contains :

```
- name: Download lib
  copy:
    src: "{{ lib_path }}/{{ lib_wheels[0] }}"
    dest: /tmp
    remote_src: true

- name: Install lib
  pip:
    name: file:///tmp/{{ lib_wheels[0] }}
  become: yes
```

It's expected it will include the **ansible/vars** which contains the **lib_wheel_path**, i f im not wrong about how ansible works

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to include the var file.
for eg: If your var file is `ansible/role/lib/vars/lib.yml`

```
local_path: "~/Some_Libraries/"
lib_wheel_path: "{{ local_path }}lib/"
```

In your playbook include it as below.

```
- name: vars
  include_vars: lib.yml

- name: Download lib
  copy:
    src: "{{ lib_path }}/{{ lib_wheels[0] }}"
    dest: /tmp
    remote_src: true

- name: Install lib
  pip:
    name: file:///tmp/{{ lib_wheels[0] }}
  become: yes
```